# Copy the value of a column in a dataframe in a json column upon flattening the json in that dataframe

Tags: json, python-3.x, dataframe

I am working on the marketing data returned by an API response. The data has columns like "id", "creation_date" and so on, along with a column "metadata" with JSON values that upon flattening contains about 26 additional columns.

[image]

I've been able to flatten the JSON in a different dataframe but I want to include the column "id" in that dataframe now. Even better have the whole dataset along with the flattened JSON in the same dataframe. The flattened JSON dataframe looks like as shown below:

[image]

The challenge here is that some of the JSON values have two sets of arguments for the some of the same corresponding rows (aka same "id"). So, if there are 21 rows (one row for each id), the JSON column upon flattening has 26 rows. There are no common columns in the JSON set of key-values or the remaining dataframe for me to inner join them either.